# Mounting directories on demand or until logged

Tags: scripting, automounting, lightdm, unmounting, logout

As from object, I want to mount some directories (with binding) at login and possibly unmount them at logout.

At the beginning I tought about autofs, but it dynamically creates mount points, that's ok with cli, but not when using filemanagers, it's really annoying to have to write a directory name to make it spawn.

Another solution I considered is running a login script, and it works. My problem now is that I don't know how to unmount them. I use LightDM, so `.bash_logout` is not an option, and also if that login manager can trigger a script when logging out, it runs system wide, and I'd prefer a solution user based.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can configure autofs to present directory names even when the underlying filesystem is not mounted. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: What logout script are you referring to ? session-cleanup-script ? In which case it is called with USER/LOGNAME/HOME set. What about testing them in the script before deciding to unmount or not ? (I can provide more details if needed)

Comment: @ChrisDavies it's exactly what I was trying to do, but I can't figure out which option I have to set.

Comment: @MC68020 Yes, session-cleanup-script. I didn't know those env vars get set. Can you please tell me where I can find more details on the documentation? I excluded to test the mountpoints in the script as general approach because I'm looking for a cleaner and a more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a possible solution resorting to some logout script, LighDM conforms to the [freedesktop specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/LightDM/CommonConfiguration/) which, given this setting :

```
[SeatDefaults]
…
session-cleanup-script=command
…
```

Will trigger command to be

> run after a greeter or user session stops. It is run as root.

Since, according to some [LightDM mailing list thread on the topic](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/lightdm/2012-December/000335.html) :

> scripts are called with USER/LOGNAME/HOME set,

You should simply be able to design a user dependent logout script.